# Line break after second word and coloring

Tags: javascript, line, cpu-word, break

I have a product title "Pillow BALANCE purple" and I want after the second word to line break. Like below.

Pillow BALANCE
purple

this title has a class lets say "title". I use the following code to change the color of the first word "Pillow" but I need to change the color for the second too and of course make the third word to go to a second line. Any help would be apreciated.

```
//add span to first word of module title, page heading
window.addEvent ('domready', function () {
    var els = $$('.art-postcontent h2 a, .art-postcontent h2 a:link, .art-postcontent h2 a:hover, .art-postcontent h2 a:visited, .art-blockcontent h2 a, .art-blockcontent h2 a:link, .art-blockcontent h2 a:hover, .art-blockcontent h2 a:visited');
    if (!els.length) return;
    els.each (function(el){
         var html = el.innerHTML;
         var text = el.get("text");
         var pos = text.indexOf(' ');
         if (pos!=-1) {
            text = text.substr(0,pos);
         }
         el.set("html", el.get("text").replace(new RegExp (text), '<span class="first-word">'+text+'</span>'));

    });
});
```

Comment: Look up `split()`. It will be helpful. Usually, you will want to take the string apart that you get from the DOM. You did the first part of that. Do all three words. Then build the HTML you want to replace them with and put it back. (What you did with the regex may not be a good idea. Use string concatenation.)

Answer (score 0):

Use of the split() function should help you here.

```
var str = 'pillow BALANCE purple';
var substr = str.split(' ');    //splits the string at each space (&nbsp;)

$('#firstLine').text(substr[0] + substr[1]);  //adds first two words to first line
$('#secondLine').text(substr[2]);  //add third word to second line
```

HTML:

```
<div id="firstLine"></div>
<br />     <!-- Break will put the next div on a new line -->
<div id="secondLine"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work. Maybe I didn't explain properly what I needed. The "Pillow BALANCE purple" is a product name and is called by this code <?php echo $productTitle ?>  You can see it here http://www.ninetteart.com/nart. It is the name of any product and I really need to have the first two words on the first line and the others to follow bellow. I don't know if this is possible and of course if I am explaining what I want correctly. Thanks anyway for your time to help.

Comment: well, before looking at the example posted, I can tell you a convention is necessary.  you say you want the first two words...so as long as your products follow the convention "word word word" (each word followed by a space) then this will indeed work.  split(' ') takes the string and breaks it apart at each space popping the substrings into an array.  then you can call each word individually by calling the index of the array...so the first two words would always be array[0] and array[1] respectively